# Search html tags with certain IDs, pulled from array, and change background color if ID from array and ID from html tag (div) match - how to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, background, styles, getelementbyid

I cannot insert dynamicly IDs (car names) from array, to search through html and change background color to matched html tags with this IDs (car names).

```
<div id="Fiat">Fiat</div>
<div id="Saab">Saab</div>
<div id="Volvo">Volvo</div>
<div id="Mercedes">Mercedes</div>
<div id="BMW">BMW</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cars = new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");

for (i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(cars[i]).style.background ='red';
}

</script>
```

I SOLVED IT. Don't know what i did, but i guess i had to ask you :-), to tell me it works. I could swear i already tried this and it didn't work. Two days i've been dealing with this.

OK, this is actually the whole code, maybe it will help someone.

The idea is to pass multiple ids through one url parameter, split ids in array, and color matched tags with passed ids.

In short, to style tags directly from url.

SOLUTION:

sample url: /test.html?type=Volvo-BMW-Fiat

It will color Volvo, BMW and Fiat.

This is the whole code, and it WORKS :-):

```
<div id="Fiat">Fiat</div>
<div id="Saab">Saab</div>
<div id="Volvo">Volvo</div>
<div id="Mercedes">Mercedes</div>
<div id="BMW">BMW</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

//function to get url parameter
function getUrlparameter( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

//store type url parameter from function in variable
var urlparameter = getUrlparameter( 'type' );

//convert urlparameter to array, split to array elements
var array = urlparameter.split("-");

//loop array elements and change background
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(array[i]) != null) {
    document.getElementById(array[i]).style.background ='red';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should post some HTML

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: Works like a charm in IE9 and Chrome. What is the problem?

Comment: hello, it doesn't work. I mean, divs with ids Saab, Vovlo and BMW should get red backgrounds, bur they don't.

Comment: uau, that is crazy, it works now, i've be dealing with this for second day now

Comment: Your array should be declared like `var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", BMW"]`

Comment: Hm, this is just a part of code, something must break it.

Comment: Ok i will prepare whole code

Comment: I found out what the problem was. If i had an ID in url, which actually didn't exist as html tag with that ID, loop just stopped.

My 'fortune' was, when i was testing, i had non-existing ID as first in URL parameter, so loop stopped immediately and i thought it is not working.

Now i added this check:
if (document.getElementById(array[i]) != null) { ... }..

The thing is now waterproof ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably one of timing. Without a live example of the code failing i cannot be 100% sure.

The timing issue is that you call document.getElementById() before the document is ready. Move your JavaScript code at the end of the BODY tag or place it as a handler for the document.ready event:

```
<body>
<div id="Fiat">Fiat</div>
<div id="Saab">Saab</div>
<div id="Volvo">Volvo</div>
<div id="Mercedes">Mercedes</div>
<div id="BMW">BMW</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var cars = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];

for (i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(cars[i]).style.background ='red';
}
</script>
</body>
```

PS: I also changed your array initialization to an array literal. It was not wrong to use new Array, but the usual way is with array literals.

Comment: I must have missed something, it works now, thank you very much.